# Use functions of other files is other directories Golang

Tags: go, model-view-controller

I want to use a method that is in a folder called "controllers" inside my main method, but it turns out that when I start the program it says that the function is not found or defined, I tried following the package guide in the Golang documentation but with the Go build and Go install this did not work, I would like to know only how to use files that are inside other folders to be able to have more order, here the codes and my file tree, first: UserController.go, here is the funcionLoadRecordsFromFile()... (Repeat... i tried using the go build and go install from the documentation but dont work...)

```
package main
import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)
func LoadRecordsFromFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Maximum upload of 10 MB files
    r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)
}
```

Here is my main.Go were i want to use the function LoadRecordsFromFile() from UserController.go

```
package main
import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
    "log"
)
func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Post("/loadUsers", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        LoadRecordsFromFile(w,r)
    })

    log.Print("Server started in port 3000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r)
}
```

The archives are...

```
-GolangProject
-Main.go
-controllers
    --UserController.go
```

Comment: Could you add the actual error?

Comment: You need to import the package in which the identifier that you want to reference is declared. You also need to package-qualify that identifier when you're referencing it.

Comment: @MayankPatel The actual error is: The console say: "undefined: LoadRecordsFromFile"

Comment: @mkopriva Can you explain a little bit more please?

Comment: @GiovanniMosquera you can directly reference only identifiers declared in the same package, i.e. same folder (non-recursive, i.e. subfolders don't count). Any other identifier, apart from builtin ones, must be referenced with a package qualifier, but to be able to use package qualified identifiers you first need to import the package you're trying to use. Just like you're importing `chi` and referencing NewRouter using `chi.NewRouter` the same way you need to import your controllers package and reference the function by qualifying it with the package's name.

Comment: @mkopriva I have tried adding `import" controllers "`, but when I tried to run it, the console responds with: package controllers is not in GOROOT (/ usr / local / go / src / controllers)
Should something be done before? ...

Comment: Please read [How to write go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) from the official docs.

Comment: @GiovanniMosquera, what's your project directory ? Can you provide the result of running the `pwd` command from your project directory ?

Comment: @Adrian I have already read it but I have not understood very well, I have tried several ways and investigated but it does not work for me, that's why I resorted to StackOverflow

Comment: @MasudurRahman `/home/giovanni/Documentos/PruebaTruora`
This is the pwd

Comment: @GiovanniMosquera, sorry, that's not I expected. If you have a `go.mod` file in your project, could you provide the first line of that file ?

Comment: @GiovanniMosquera What is in your  UserController.go file?

Comment: *"I have already read it but I have not understood very well"* Then you should re-read it and keep re-reading it until you understand. @GiovanniMosquera

Comment: @MasudurRahman This is the first line of go.mod `module github.com/Giovanni2414/Truora`

Comment: @MayankPatel in the question statement is the code inside UserController.go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make some changes in your code.

1. At first, you need to change your package name in your `UserController.go`. Lets just use `controllers` as package.

   ```golang
   package controllers

   import (
       "net/http"
       "log"
   )
   func LoadRecordsFromFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       // Maximum upload of 10 MB files
       r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)
   }
   ```
2. Then your `Main.go` needs some changes.

   ```golang
   package main

   import (
       "net/http"
       "github.com/go-chi/chi"
       "log"

       "github.com/Giovanni2414/Truora/controllers"
   )

   func main() {
       r := chi.NewRouter()
       r.Post("/loadUsers", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
           controllers.LoadRecordsFromFile(w,r)
       })

       log.Print("Server started in port 3000")
       http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r)
   }
   ```

These changes are enough I think.

---

Some notes:

- Only your main file should have `package main`.
- Normally we define package name after our `current folder` (*but it can be different*). All the files under same folder must have same `package` name.
- When you use a function that is under a different package, you should import the desired package before you can use that function. 
  Your imported path should be like this: `<project-module-name>/<folder1>/<folder2>/../<final-folder>`.
- Finally, you should call that function like the following:

  ```golang
  package_name.MyFunction()
  ```

Comment: Now my code works fine!, I'm really very grateful to you, and also thank you very much for not telling me to "read how to read code" like several others :)

Comment: @GiovanniMosquera, I have added some notes to my answer. You should check it out.